# Exceeding LLM's maximum context length even using llama_index PromptHelper

Tags: prompt, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

I've been struggling with llama_index's PromptHelper and can't find a solution anywhere on the Internet.

But first let me talk about my use case:

I'm trying to use Azure OpenAI's GPT-3.5 model to ask the model to make a summary of comments posted by users in an Instagram post, passing in the prompt as a system message all the comments and then asking a question like: "What's the general sentiment in the comments?".

The problem here is that there are so many comments and in many publications I exceed gpt-35-turbo-16k's 16384 tokens maximum context length. Trying to solve this issue I've been working with llama_index's PromptHelper that, if I'm not mistaken helps divide the prompt in chunks in this kind of situations. The problem is that I keep getting the same error no matter in how many ways I change PromptHelper's parameters:

```
InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 16384 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 22272 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing it up in something in my code but can't find where, and llama_index's documentation is not helping me much.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my code, just in case someone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong:

```py
from llama_index.llms import AzureOpenAI
from llama_index.llms.base import ChatMessage
from llama_index.chat_engine import SimpleChatEngine
from llama_index import ServiceContext, PromptHelper
from llama_index.text_splitter import TokenTextSplitter
from llama_index.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser

import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

csv_files = glob.glob('data/csv/*.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(
    csv_files[1],
    sep='|'
)
context_comments = df['COMENTARIO'].to_list()

context_message = f"""Estos son los comentarios que los usuarios han dejado en una publicación de una empresa de supermercados en diferentes redes sociales: \n \
                                        {context_comments}. \n \
                                        Se te van a hacer preguntas sobre los comentarios de la misma, a las que deberás responder con precisión, \
                                        como si estuvieras redactando un informe para los responsables de la publicación, que quieren saber la acogida que ha tenido."""
prefix_messages = [ChatMessage(content=context_message, role="system")]

# Define the LLM
llm = AzureOpenAI(
    model=MODEL_NAME,
    engine=DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
    api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    api_base=AZURE_BASE_URL,
    api_type="azure",
    api_version="2023-05-15"
)

node_parser = SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults(
  text_splitter=TokenTextSplitter(chunk_size=512, chunk_overlap=20)
)

# Define prompt helper
prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
  context_window=16384,
  num_output=1500,
  chunk_overlap_ratio=0.2,
  separator="\n"
)

# Create the service context
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm,
    prompt_helper=prompt_helper,
    node_parser=node_parser,
    embed_model=None,
    chunk_size=512,
    context_window=16384,
    num_output=1500
)

# Use SimpleChatEngine to mix it all
chat_engine = SimpleChatEngine.from_defaults(
    service_context=service_context,
    verbose=True,
    prefix_messages=prefix_messages
)

response = chat_engine.chat("Cual es el sentimiento general de los comentarios de la publicacion?")

print(response)
```

It throws the same error as mentioned above.